# How to iterate through a vector of nodes

Tags: c++, vector, graph, dijkstra, shortest-path

I am implementing Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm. I have made a node class as follows:

```
node::node(int to,int weight)
{
    this->to = to;
    this->weight = weight;
}
```

I have made a graph class as :

```
class Graph
{
    int V,E;
    vector<node> *adj;
    public :
        Graph(int V,int E);
        void addEdge(int v,int w,int weight);
        void dijkstra(int src,int V);
};

Graph::Graph(int V,int E)
{
    this->V = V;
    this->E = E;
}

void Graph::addEdge(int v,int w,int weight)
{
    node x(w,weight);
    adj[v].push_back(x);
    node y(v,weight);
    adj[w].push_back(y);
}
```

Now in Dijkstra's algorithm function, I want to iterate through adjacency list (**here vector**):

```
void Graph::dijkstra(int src,int V)
{
    struct heap_node node[V];
    for(int i=0;i<V;i++)
    {
        node[i].vertex_value = INT_MAX;
        node[i].vertex_no = i;
    }
    bool visited[V];
    memset(visited,false,sizeof(visited));
    node[src].vertex_value = 0;
    make_heap(node,node+V,compare);
    //As we have set vertex_value(distance from source) of the source node to 0,We are left with V-1 vertices. So, we will run a for loop. 
    for(int i=0;i<V-1;i++)  
    {
        pop_heap(node,node-i-1,compare);
        //This will extract the minimum from the heap and set it to the last position. 
        int cur = V-i-1;
        int u = node[cur].vertex_no;
        visited[u] = true;
        vector<node>::iterator it;
        for(it = adj[u].begin() ; it != adj[u].end() ; it++)
        {
            node v = *it;
        }
    }
}
```

But it gives me the following errors:

**dijkstra1.cpp: In member function ‘void Graph::dijkstra(int, int)’:
dijkstra1.cpp:79:10: error: ‘node’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
   vector::iterator it;**

**dijkstra1.cpp:79:14: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   vector::iterator it;**

**dijkstra1.cpp:79:14: error: template argument 2 is invalid**

**dijkstra1.cpp:79:26: error: expected initializer before ‘it’
   vector::iterator it;**

**dijkstra1.cpp:80:7: error: ‘it’ was not declared in this scope
   for(it = adj[u].begin() ; it != adj[u].end() ; it++)**

How do I get rid of that.

Comment: You changed the meaning of `node` here: `struct heap_node node[V];`. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you have two types: heap_node, and a node class.
I'm not sure which type is adj, but either way, you cannot make the vector type an instance. it has to be a type. So either make it

```
typedef struct heap_node HEAP_NODE_STRUCT
vector<HEAP_NODE_STRUCT>
```

or c
hange the 
`heap_node struct node`
 to

```
heap_node struct the_heap_node;
```

So you do not hide the original node class.